# Sign flipping Fourier transform Python Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I have data that is the sign of data in a numpy array:

```
Data=[-1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,...,N]
```

There is an obvious pattern from inspection where every 3rd element is negative:

```
Pattern=[1,1-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1...]
```

But there is noise so I cant directly quantify this, so I would like to do a fourier transform to see how strong this spatial repetition is.

I would expect to see a large peak at frequency=N/3 since this pattern seems to repeat every 3 values.

So far I have tried:

For a data of N=401 I have tried:

```
y=numpy.fft.fft(Data)
x = np.linspace(0,400,401)

plt.plot(x,y.real) 
plt.show()
```

but I am getting noise and no clear peaks which I know exist. I have a feeling I am not implementing the fft correctly.

Comment: what happens if you use the absolute value of `y` instead of its real part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some test with a toy example and it seems to work.
You should probably plot the absolute value or the PSD but the peaks are there also if you plot just the real part.

```
# array with a -1 every third element
a = np.tile([1,1,-1], 100)

# add some noise
b = a * np.random.choice([-1, 1], len(a), p=[0.1, 0.9])

x = np.linspace(0, len(a), len(a+1))
y = np.fft.fft(b)

plt.plot(x[1:], y[1:].real); plt.show()
```

[image]

```
plt.plot(x[1:], np.abs(y[1:]**2)); plt.show()
```

[image]